# Why PostgreSQL queries are slower in the first request after first new connection than during the subsequent requests?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why PostgreSQL queries are slower in the first request after first new connection than during the subsequent requests?

Using several different technologies to connect to a postgresql database.  First request might take 1.5 seconds.  Exact same query will take .03 seconds the second time.  Open a second instance of my application (connecting to same database) and that first request takes 1.5 seconds and the second .03 seconds.

Because of the different technologies we are using they are connecting at different points and using different connection methods so I really don't think it has anything to do with any code I have written.

I'm thinking that opening a connection doesn't do 'everything' until the first request, so that request has some overhead.

Because I have used the database, and kept the server up everything is in memory so index and the like should not be an issue.

**Edit** Explain - tells me about the query and honestly the query looks pretty good (indexed, etc).  I really think postgresql has some kind of overhead on the first query of a new connection.

I don't know how to prove/disprove that.  If I used PG Admin III (pgAdmin version 1.12.3) all the query's seem fast.  Any of the other tools I have the first query is slow.  Most the time its not noticeably slower, and if it was I always chalked it up to updating the ram with the index.  But this is clearly NOT that.  If I open my tool(s) and do any other query that returns results the second query is fast regardless.  If the first query doesn't return results then the second is still slow, then third is fast.

**edit 2**
Even though I don't think the query has anything to do with the delay (every first query is slow) here are two results from running Explain (EXPLAIN ANALYZE)

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
 select * from company
 where company_id = 39
```

Output:

```
"Seq Scan on company  (cost=0.00..1.26 rows=1 width=54) (actual time=0.037..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Filter: (company_id = 39)"
"Total runtime: 0.085 ms"
```

and:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select * from group_devices
where device_name ilike 'html5_demo'
and group_id in ( select group_id from manager_groups
where company_id in (select company_id from company where company_name ='TRUTHPT'))
```

output:

```
"Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=1.26..45.12 rows=1 width=115) (actual time=1.947..2.457 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: (group_devices.group_id = manager_groups.group_id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on group_devices  (cost=0.00..38.00 rows=1 width=115) (actual time=0.261..0.768 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((device_name)::text ~~* 'html5_demo'::text)"
"  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1.26..7.09 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.297..1.596 rows=46 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (manager_groups.company_id = company.company_id)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on manager_groups  (cost=0.00..5.53 rows=509 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.676 rows=469 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1.26..1.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on company  (cost=0.00..1.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((company_name)::text = 'TRUTHPT'::text)"
"Total runtime: 2.566 ms"
```

Comment: Why PostgreSQL queries are slower in the first request after first new connection than during the subsequent requests?  Yep, perhaps not a great explaination of what is happening - first line is a question.

Comment: Okay, yeah from what I saw on it, it looked like you asked a question and answered it yourself. Maybe I read it wrong.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a simple query, like `select 1;`?  How about `select * from pgbench_accounts where aid=987`

Comment: @jjanes yes any first query (that returns a result) will be slow.  IF I do a query and it doesn't return a result the first query that has a result will be slow.

Comment: Very odd.  Are you connecting to the local machine, or over the network?  Can you reproduce it with every client you use or just some?  How about just `psql`?  If you intentionally connect with the wrong password, how long does it take to get the error message back?

Comment: See same behavior on both production and development databases.  I don't have the tools installed on the servers that host the databases, but have a hard time believing that it is tcp/ip related because of the 0 result not 'fixing it.  Bad username returns in an instant.

Comment: *I really think postgresql has some kind of overhead on the first query of a new connection*. It doesn't, at least nothing more than trivial. Are you using PL/Java or some other extension that requires a heavyweight startup? Do you have anything in your `shared_preload_libraries` setting? What is your `max_connections` setting? What's `shared_buffers` set to?

Comment: **You must show two `explain analyze` plans for the same query, one when it's fast, one when it's slow**. Otherwise we cannot help you. Showing plans for two unrelated queries is not helpful. Actually, I'd prefer that you use `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE, VERBOSE)` rather than `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` unless that gives you a syntax error. Finally: *what PostgreSQL version are you on*?

Comment: @CraigRinger ack. I might just have to build something, everything I have is coupled with a bunch of stuff so I can't really put that in place.

Comment: Did you figure out the root cause of this behavior?

Comment: @SameerNaik I did not

Answer (score 4):

I have observed the same behavior.  If I start a new connection, and run a query multiple times, the first execution is about 25% slower than the following executions.  (This query has been run earlier in other connections, and I have verified that there is no disk I/O involved.)  I profiled the process with perf during the first query execution, and this is what I found:

[image]

As you can see, a lot of time is spent handling page faults. If I profile the second execution, there are no page faults.  AFAICT, these are what is called minor/soft page faults.  This happens when a process for the first time access a page that is in shared memory.  At that point, the process needs to map the page into its virtual address space (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). If the page needs to be read from disk, it is called as major/hard page fault.

This explanation also fits with other observations that I have made:  If I later run a different query in the same connection, the amount of overhead for its first execution seems to depend on how much overlap there is with the data accessed by the first query.

Answer (score 1):

This a very old question, but hopefully this may help.

**First query**

It doesn't seem like an index is being used, and the optimizer is resorting to a sequential scan of the table.
While scanning the table sequentially, the optimizer may cache the entire table in RAM, if the data fits into the buffer. See [this article](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/hw_performance/) for more information.
Why the buffering is occurring for each connection I don't know. Regardless, a sequential scan is not desirable for this kind of query and can be avoided with correct indexing and statistics.

Check the structure of the `company` table. Make sure that `company_id` is part of a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY`.
Make sure you run `ANALYZE`, so that the optimizer has the correct statistics. This will help to ensure that the index for `company` will be used in your queries instead of a sequential scan of the table.

See [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-examine.html)

**Second query**

Try using `INNER JOIN` to avoid the optimizer selecting `Hash Semi Join`, to get more consistent performance and a simplier `EXPLAIN PLAN`:

```
select gd.*
from group_devices gd
inner join manager_groups mg on mg.group_id = gd.group_id
inner join company c on c.company_id = mg.company_id
where gd.device_name like 'html5_demo%'
and c.company_name = 'TRUTHPT';
```

See [related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7378/should-i-use-sql-join-or-in-clause)

Comment: I left this job about 10 months ago, but while it is sound advice in your answer it doesn't answer the question about the 1st vs 2nd query per connection. Remember I could have 2 different connections open and run the same query on both - both will be slow. So the first results returned to have some added overhead that I could not figure out or find any explanation for.

Comment: I understand. My answer would reduce the likelyhood of the sequential scan. It is more focussed on avoiding the situation by tuning the SQL, rather than explaning the quirks of the optimizer (which could have a bug in that version, or an install/configuration issue on the host)..

Answer (score -1):

First request will read blocks from disk to buffers.
Second request will read from buffers.

It doesnt matter how many connections are made, the result is dependant on whether that query has already been parsed.

Please note changing literals will reparse the query
Also note that if the query hasnt been executed in a while then physical reads may still occur depending on many variables.

Comment: Except I am seeing that on each connection the first query on the new connection is slower.  I can run the query 100 times in a row on one connection.  Open new application run the same query and it will be much slower.

Comment: Can you attach an explain plan for a couple examples?

Comment: PostgreSQL's `shared_buffers` are just that - shared across all instances. So is the operating system disk cache. So this isn't a caching effect. If it was, then the first query would be slow then the second faster irrespective of which session each was run on.

Comment: Depends if the queries were different for the second session. When I wrote that reply we had no evidence of what the queries are.